# how to make a scanned PDF text-selectable using ghostscript and gsview

Tags: pdf

I have a scanned PDF file and it is not searchable and not text-selectable. Tell me how to convert this kind of PDFs to a text-enabled and searchable one. I'm a bit familiar with gsview and have ghostscript installed on my PC if these programs can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those will by themselves.

Scans are images. What you need to convert a picture of text to actual text is [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition). [Ghostscript supports OCR with Tesseract.](https://www.ghostscript.com/ocr.html) There's also a number of OCR applications, free and paid. One such freeware that utilizes Tesseract is [OCRmyPDF](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), downloadable from [Github](https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF).

Tests and recommendations can be found searching something along the lines of "best ocr applications".

There are also some websites that can do it, but the ones I've seen are either limited (for example to 3 pages without pay) or the quality has been terrible.

Comment: TY. will share my findings as soon as find the best ocr application

Comment: PDF-XChange application for Windows is my choice. Also for advanced users, I suggest ocrmypdf that is multi-platform.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :-) If this helped, could you please accept the answer? That way it gets out of the Unaccepted-queue, and someone else with the same issue can identify this one as solution. Added OCRmyPDF to the answer.